# How to get churn rate in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, metrics

Is it possible to get the churn rate of my ecommerce in google analytics? I don't how to use (or if is necessary) bounce rate to calculate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Of course, for example with enhanced ecommerce you can determine the abundance rate at each checkout step.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce